# Pytest fails when using pyhamcrest raises

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, python-unittest, hamcrest, pyhamcrest

Currently I have a test cases like the following:

```py
    def test_foo(self):
        assert_that(self.target.do(), raises(FileNotFoundError))
```

Which passes using the standard python unittest framework, however if I change to use pytest, it fails. Switching to the pytest syntax works (as below), but why doesn't the pyhamcrest matcher work in this case?

```py
    def test_foo(self):
        with pytest.raises(FileNotFoundError):
             self.target.do()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyHamcrest's [`raises()`](https://pyhamcrest.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.8/object_matchers/#hamcrest.core.core.raises.raises) matcher requires you to make the call with the [`calling()`](https://pyhamcrest.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.8/object_matchers/#hamcrest.core.core.raises.calling) function - see the [tutorial](https://pyhamcrest.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.8/tutorial/#asserting-exceptions). So, in your case you'd want:

```py
assert_that(calling(self.target.do), raises(FileNotFoundError))
```